# Как лучше записать данные в БД

Tags: mysql

**Цель: записать в DB какие уровни прошел пользователь, чтобы потом легко было сделать выборку.**

Есть два варианта:

1. Записывать каждый раз новую запись в таблицу. `id_user`, `id_level`
2. Записывать один раз в БД и в поле `id_levels` ставить много
   идентификаторов (01,22,31). Потом проверять через `search -> id_levels`

Как лучше?

Comment: Все зависит от того, как вы будете этими данными пользоваться.
Если надо знать, какие юзвери прошли определенный уровень - первый вариант лучше.
Если надо знать, какие уровни прошел юзверь, второй вариант тоже вполне себе.
Но вообще вопрос некорректен.

Comment: Согласен. На вопрос сложно однозначно ответить. О каких идентификаторах идет речь? Что, кроме номера уровня, еще Вам надо хранить?

Comment: Вообще главный запрос будет - Прошел ли этот юзер этот уровень?

Comment: А, т.е. пользователь может прыгать с уровня на уровень, пропуская некоторые?

Comment: Да, может прыгать. Просто у каждого юзера могут быть по 100-200 пройденных уровней если будет первый вариант не будет ли это много записей для БД?

Comment: @Vadim для базы и миллионы записей - это мелочи)

Comment: @Vadim Миллионы конечно не особо страшно для БД, но если _все_ запросы в БД касаются только пройденных уровней одного игрока - то выборка 100 записей будет работать явно дольше, чем получение одного поля.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше записывать каждый раз новой записью. Как минимум потому что, как я предполагаю, необходим не просто факт прохождения, но и мета данные всякие: время прохождения и т.п.

Да и даже если нет, то в будущем вы возможно захотите сохранять какие-то данные конкретные по результатам прохождения. Лучше сразу про это подумать и писать каждый раз отдельной записью.

Плюс поиск проще будет. Скажем, если вам необходимо найти количество игроков, которые прошли какой-то уровень. Если вы будете хранить в одной записи в массиве, то это будет сложно.

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от того, что потом делать с этой информацией. Каноны реляционных баз данных (нормальная форма) говорят нам, что нужна отдельная таблица с отдельными записями на уровень.

Если информация о пройденых уровнях может потребоваться где либо в виде "дай всех игроков прошедших уровень N" или будет собираться статистика какие уровни сколько игроков прошли - то безусловно специальная таблица с многими записями.

Если информация касается только данного игрока. Получается только в ключе "какие уровни прошел игрок XX". То поле с перечисленными уровнями - неплохое решение. Хотя лично я в такой ситуации пожалуй сделал бы битовую маску, по 1 биту на уровень.